# Проблема с музыкальным ботом

Tags: python, discord.py

Я нашёл что-то на подобие [youtube-dl](/questions/tagged/youtube-dl), и вроде написал всё правильно, но выбивает ошибку.

---

Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp



intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)

FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn', 'executable': 'C:\\Users\\DeN\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\ffmpeg'}
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    vc = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        if 'https://' in url:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        else:
            info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{url}", download=False)['entries'][0]
    link = info['formats'][0]['url']
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))





print('ready')
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\test.py", line 21, in play
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 290, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 166, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 180, in _spawn_process
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DeN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\DeN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
[2023-09-30 01:50:04] [ERROR   ] discord.voice_client: Disconnected from voice... Reconnecting in 1.82s.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 461, in poll_voice_ws
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "C:\Users\DeN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 1011, in poll_event
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.ws, shard_id=None, code=self._close_code)
discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 4006
[2023-09-30 01:50:05] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: The voice handshake is being terminated for Channel ID 1088869297046175798 (Guild ID 1088869296425414727)
[2023-09-30 01:50:05] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Connecting to voice...
[2023-09-30 01:50:05] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 2)
[2023-09-30 01:50:06] [INFO    ] discord.voice_client: Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found bucharest4450.discord.media
[2023-09-30 01:50:59] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has stopped responding to the gateway. Closing and restarting.
```